# LSTM with rule-based features?

Tags: python, classification, lstm

I trained an LSTM with an Embedding layer that should classify Tweets into ironic (class 1, 2 or 3) and not ironic. Is there a way to tell the network to additionally look at a specific feature like mean punctuation in the tweets? I already have an array with the mean punctuation per tweet. This is my model I want to improve:

```py
inputs = Input(shape=(MAX_LEN, ))
embedding_layer = Embedding(vocab_size,
                            128,
                            input_length=MAX_LEN)(inputs)

x = LSTM(64)(embedding_layer)
x = Dropout(0.5)(x)
x = Dense(32, activation='relu')(x)
predictions = Dense(num_class, activation='softmax')(x)
model = Model(inputs=[inputs], outputs=predictions)
model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['acc'])

model.summary()

filepath="weights.hdf5"
checkpointer = ModelCheckpoint(filepath, monitor='val_acc', verbose=1, save_best_only=True, mode='max')
history = model.fit([X_train], batch_size=64, y=to_categorical(y_train), verbose=1, validation_split=0.25, 
          shuffle=True, epochs=20, callbacks=[checkpointer])
```

Comment: Note that at the end of the network, you have some dense layers.  You can just cat whatever you want to onto the end of those vectors before feeding them into the dense layers.

Comment: If you cat it onto the very last dense layer, you can think of the whole model as a multinomial logit with the lstm features and also mean punctuation as the input, and class as output.

Comment: So, before the predictions layer I would have to stack the mean_punct array to the x?

Comment: That's one way to do it.  Note that `x` might include a batch dimension so you'll have to deal with all that mess.  Might be easiest to put the mean_punct onto `x` *before* input, then [split](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/2801) `x` at the very beginning, catting the mean_punct dimensions back on at the prediction layer.  I'm no keras expert tho, so implementation details are above my pay grade.  :)

Comment: you mean before inputs = Input(shape=(MAX_LEN, ))?

Comment: before `model.fit([X_train]`.  Put the extra dims into `X_train`.

Comment: then split after `Input`

Comment: then join before `prediction`